Removing Space between a table Header and the Entries below
I would like to know if there is a way to remove the gray space between the view header (Category   Local/Home Amount) and entries below.

On other views that don't use onDelete I have been able to use scrollView below the VStack to make the space disappear. (I want the header to remain visible when the view is scrolled.) See example code below.
struct DataView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { g in
            VStack {
                ShowTotalsHeader(g: g)
                
                ScrollView {
                    
                    if g.size.height > g.size.width {
                        PortraitTotals(g: g)
                        
                    } else {
                        LandscapeTotals(g: g)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


The code below uses onDelete. If I insert ScrollView just above the call to the header all I see in the view is the header without any entries.
Is there a different way to remove the space between the header and the entries?
struct HistoryView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query(sort: \TravelEntries.entryDate, order: .forward) var travelEntries: [TravelEntries]
    var entryDate: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                ShowHistoryHeader(g: g)
                
                List {
                    ForEach(travelEntries) { item in

                        if g.size.height > g.size.width { // portrait ?
                            ShowProtrait(g: g, item: item, entryDate: entryDate)  // portrait
                        } else {
                            
                            ShowLandscape(g: g, item: item, entryDate: entryDate)  // landscape
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(Color.myTop, for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Text("History")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    


